# Geodjango insert statement: psycopg2.IntegrityError: violates check constraint

Tags: sql, geodjango

Why is the following INSERT statement throwing this error?

```
INSERT INTO domes_place (placeid, structidx, oscode) VALUES ('10', '1', 'POINT(51.121282945772 1.3138398501222)');
psycopg2.IntegrityError: new row for relation "domes_place" violates check constraint "enforce_srid_oscode"
```

This is the table definition in postgres:

```
           Table "public.domes_place"
   Column   |          Type          | Modifiers 
------------+------------------------+-----------
 placeid    | integer                | not null
 structidx  | integer                |  
 oscode     | geometry               | 
Check constraints:
    "enforce_dims_oscode" CHECK (st_ndims(oscode) = 2)
    "enforce_geotype_oscode" CHECK (geometrytype(oscode) = 'POINT'::text OR oscode IS NULL)
    "enforce_srid_oscode" CHECK (st_srid(oscode) = 4326)
```

Isn't this POINT in WGS84 - i.e. in SRID 4326?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out.

For the benefit of others, the oscode column needed to be specified as follows:

```
 ST_GeomFromText('POINT(51.146991053359 1.3585857857582)',4326),
```